# FastAPI pytest returning 404 not found

Tags: pytest, fastapi

I am attempting to use pytest to test a FastAPI method exists. Why is the is code returning a 404 error for the pytest?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()

client = TestClient(app)

def test_read_main():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Error:

```
E       assert 404 == 200
E        +  where 404 = <Response [404 Not Found]>.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because I needed to import and reuse the same app variable FastAPI object in the TestClient. Here is the working code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from .main import app
app = FastAPI()

client = TestClient(app)

def test_read_main():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello World"}
```